# Flutter - OneSignal - setNotificationOpenedHandler - OpenPage

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, onesignal

I have a flutter app.
I am using OneSignal push notification.
I want to open a page when the notification is clicked. However, when it is clicked first, there is no page transition because it cannot find the context. How can I open the relevant page when the notification is clicked on?

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
        try {
         Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: RouteSettings(name: '/a'),
              builder: (context) => Settings(),
            ),
          );
        }
        catch(e) {
          print('e : ' + e.toString());
        }
        
      });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a GlobalKey for your MaterialApp and use the router without context. I use it to redirect users to login page if an unauthorized status code is found on my http controllers.

First I created a class with the key:

```
class NavigatorKey {static final key = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();}
```

Then in my MaterialApp:

```
...
return MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: key
...
```

And then I import the class and use the key like this:

```
NavigatorKey.key.currentState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (r) => false);
```